# Secure http transfer with ssh (tunnel)?

Tags: php, ssh, http, httpd

I have two servers which communicate over http. I wish this transfer be secure.

How can this be achieved? I do not wish to use use https (that would require ssl certificate,right?)

[**SERVER-I**] --> [**SSH-ENDPOINT]** -<->--<->--<->-**HTTP**-<->--<->--<->- [**SSH-ENDPOINT**] <--[**SERVER-II**]

Is something like this ^^ possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All is possible ! `ssh -C -L 8080:server-II:80 SSH-ENPOINT` will established a tunnel between ssh_endpoints. Then you can ask to your server to connect to the other by using http://localhost:8080.
To the other way, you need another tunnel.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understoodd this "To the other way, you need another tunnel". Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: If the second server need to talk to the first by a secured connection, you need to establish this connection too, by ssh -C -L 8080:server-I:80 SSH-ENPOINT-I

Answer (score 4):

If your problem with using an SSL certificate is that they cost money, self-signed certificates are free and provide exactly the same encryption. [Tutorials](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) are easy to find.

If you are using curl, you can use the `-k` option to not require that your server's SSL key is signed by a CA.  The wget version of this option is `--no-check-certificate`.

Dom's solution *will* work however you will need to stay logged in or disown the ssh process from the current shell or else the tunnel will go away when you disconnect.

One method is to use `nohup` in front of the ssh command.

Another is to background the ssh process and then disown it.  You can background an ssh connection by typing `~^z` (That's a tilde followed by a ctrl-z) then use `bg` to start it running again in the background and `disown` to separate the ssh tunnel from the shell.

I'm not sure exactly how that escape sequence works with chained ssh connections.  I suspect you will need to type `~~^z` if you have used ssh to connect to server1 before using ssh to set up a tunnel between the two servers.

You may also want to use something like [Autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to restart the tunnel if it dies.  Firewalls and random network outages can easily cause the tunnel to break even if the process is still alive.

Comment: +1 for the self-signed cert idea. For internal server-server communication that's a pretty perfect solution. On top of that, if you need a paid one, GoDaddy sells them for $13/year.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like a secure VPN connection between the two servers. I've played around with having hamachi (http://www.logmein.com) installed on both servers. I was able to create a secure VPN connection between the two servers without opening up any risks of having ports opened for the VPN communication. By default the Hamachi VPN tun adapter is 100mbps which is usually okay, but could be an issue of you need something greater than that. Hamachi is also cross platform and very easy to setup.